# VideoView Fullscreen Rotation

Tags: android, orientation, android-videoview

I have a VideoView within a rather complex layout. On click of the fullscreen button the VideoView (a livestream) should fill the entire screen. I realized that by setting width/height of the VideoView to MATCH_PARENT and the visibility of all other UI elements to View.GONE.

My problem is though that the Video is always rotated to the right, meaning that depending on how the user hold his phone the Video is sometimes displayed upside down. Like shown below.[image: Fullscreen depending on rotation]

Is there a simple way to fix that?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Answer is actually pretty simple. I should RTFM I guess. When entering the fullscreen mode I just have to set

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_LANDSCAPE);
```

which locks the activity's orientation to landscape but uses sensor input to decide which way around to turn the activity.